# Как заставить консоль не закрываться при запуске jar файла двойным шелчком?

Tags: java, консоль

Написал обычный хело ворд, создал jar file через IDEA intellij, но при запуске консоль открывается и сразу закрывается. Как сделать так чтобы успеть прочесть надпись  ?  :

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        System.out.println("Hello Worlds");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

добавьте чтение из консоли после System.out.println("Hello Worlds");

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String s = in.nextLine();
```

Тогда программа ваша напечает сообщение и будет ждать от пользователья ввод данных для чтения.

Comment: попробовал не работает.  Попробуйте сами

Comment: вы после System.out.println добавили код?